# Vimeo Resumable (PUT) Uploads

Tags: file-upload, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to upload Vimeo videos from my website. I am trying to use the Resumable HTTP PUT uploads described here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos.

I can get the video uploaded using step 3. I can usually even complete the upload shown in step 5. However, it recommends verifying the upload in Step 4. Every time I perform that request, I get a 308 Resume Incomplete error.

I know the upload is complete, especially since I can complete it. Just for reference, I am using Simple Ajax Uploader (https://www.lpology.com/code/ajaxuploader/docs.php) to upload the video.

Here is my code:

```
// onComplete method for uploading the video using Simple Ajax Uploader
onComplete: function (filename, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: self.uploadUrl.value,
      method: 'PUT',
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      crossDomain: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-Range': 'bytes */*',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      },
      success: function (data, status) {
        self.videoForm.submit();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Being able to complete a video does not necessarily mean that the upload is complete. The only way to ensure the upload is complete is by verifying that the byte range in the verification response (in the range header) indicates that the entire file has been uploaded.

[edit] Also, I'm not sure that the library you linked supports Vimeo's upload workflow. This library on the other hand does: https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload